# Spring Boot. How to test http protocol version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

I'm using `Spring Boot 2.6.0` and `Spring MVC` in my application.
I want to switch my controller protocol from version `http/1.1` to `http/2`.
First of all, I've written the next integration test for that:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void canGet() {
        ResponseEntity<JsonResponse> entity = template.getForEntity("/foo", JsonResponse.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, entity.getStatusCode());
        assertNotNull(entity.getBody());
        //todo: assertEquals("http/2", entity.getProtocol());
        //todo: assertEquals("http/1.1", entity.getProtocol())
    }
}
```

But `entity.getProtocol()` method doesn't exist and I can't find any other way to test protocol version. Does anyone know how to test the protocol version correctly in spring boot application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a [simple Spring-Starter application](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.0&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web), with a (rest) controller like:

```java
@GetMapping("/foo")
public String foo() {
    return "bar";
}
```

With java >= 11, we can test the HTTP protocol version with `java.net.http` client (no additional dependencies):

```java
package com.example.test.http.version;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class IntegrationTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Test
    public void testJavaDotNet() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        java.net.http.HttpClient client = java.net.http.HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .build(); // or configure a (test) bean
        java.net.http.HttpRequest request = java.net.http.HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:" + port + "/foo"))
                .build();
        java.net.http.HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(java.net.http.HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1, response.version());
    }
}
```

Key points:

- [`HttpResponse.version()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.html#version())
- [java.net.http.HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html)

---

With java < 11 **but also alternatively**, we can use:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <!--  <version>4.5.13</version> managed via spring-boot-dependencies -->
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

..and:

```java
@Test
public void testApache() throws IOException {
    org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.create()
       .build();// or configure (test) bean(s)
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(
        new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet("http://localhost:" + port + "/foo")
    );
    org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion protocolV = response.getStatusLine().getProtocolVersion();

    assertNotNull(protocolV);
    assertEquals("HTTP", protocolV.getProtocol());
    assertEquals(1, protocolV.getMajor());
    assertEquals(1, protocolV.getMinor());
}
```

- [`HttpResponse.getStatusLine()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/latest/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getStatusLine())
- [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/)

---

Sorry, [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)!

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <!-- <version>3.14.9</version>  managed via spring-boot-dependencies -->
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And, "voila":

```java
@Test
public void testOkHttp() throws IOException {
  okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient();
  okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder().url(getUriString("/foo")).build();

  try (okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    assertEquals(okhttp3.Protocol.HTTP_1_1, response.protocol());
  } catch (RuntimeException reexc) {
    org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(reexc);
  }
}
```

- [`Response.protocol`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response/protocol/)
- [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

---

- [Sample repo at github](https://github.com/xerx593/soq70109143).

---

Probably this is not the last option...
And when you somehow manage to access the `ServletRequest` (in your test), you can issue: [getProtocol()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getProtocol()), like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9827393/592355).

Comment: I've tried with Java 11 HttpClient and it works perfectly. Thank you!
It's a pity that it can't be done with Spring tools.

Comment: thx for accept! (just added an okhttp-solution))

Comment: since both are managed by spring-boot(-dependencies), you can somewhat rely on that/call it "spring (well known) tools" ...but, i found no way (yet) with `RestTemplate` or `WebClient` ;(

Comment: [after switching to and testing  HTTP/2](https://github.com/xerx593/soq70109143/tree/http2), i can only recommend to use the `java.net.http` client, since the others don't really/intuitively support it yet.